# Prevent SVG objects from overlapping

Tags: javascript, jquery, svg

I am currently working on a Drag and drop project that requires svg shapes to connect with each other but not pass through.  I have a jsfiddle with it working with divs but not the svgs. Any help would be appreciated.

[**JSFIDDLE**](http://jsfiddle.net/ryanverdel/7Lmajy4m/)

HTML

```
<div id="container">
<div id="square" class="draggable boundaries"></div>
<div id="square" class="draggable boundaries"></div>
<div id="circle" class="draggable boundaries"></div>  
<div id="triangle-up" class="draggable boundaries"></div>  


<svg height="100" width="100" class="draggable boundaries" >

<circle cx="50" cy="50" r="40" stroke="black" stroke-width="3" fill="green"/>
Sorry, your browser does not support inline SVG.  

</svg>   

<svg height="100" width="100" class="draggable boundaries" >
<circle cx="50" cy="50" r="40" stroke="black" stroke-width="3" fill="green"/>
Sorry, your browser does not support inline SVG.  
</svg>   

</div>
```

JS

```
$(".draggable").draggable({
obstacle:".boundaries",
preventCollision: true,
containment: "#container",
start: function(event,ui) {
    $(this).removeClass('boundaries');
},
stop: function(event,ui) {
    $(this).addClass('boundaries');
}
 });
```

Comment: It appears the `draggable` is not meant to work with svg elements. You may need to write that as custom code

Comment: This plugin http://www.inkfood.com/collision-detection-with-svg/ is really neat as it uses polygons to detect precise collision.  Just need to figure out how to create an event to keep elements from overlapping each other.